# How do I "force" my Rails 3 app to use 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I have setup Rails 3.0.3 and installed Ruby 1.9.2 with rvm and set rvm to use 1.9.2 by default.

However, when I create a new rails app and check the environmental variables it still reflects ruby 1.8.7, how do I update this to 1.9.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably executing an old 1.8.7 rails binary that is being found first in your [UNIX search path](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acar.html).

You can type `which rails` at the command line to see which rails executable you are running. On my machine I get:

```
/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rails
```

You can also check your binary search path by typing `echo $PATH`

If you get a result from `which rails` that looks something like:

```
/blah/blah/gems/ruby-1.8.7/bin/rails
```

... then you need to remove the old rails binary from your path, or use the old 1.8.7 ruby to uninstall the rails gems, so that they are not found and executed.

Once you have done this, the next time you try to execute `rails s`, the 1.9.2 version of the rails binary should be executed.

Answer (score 3):

With RVM, there is actually an easier way to set the default Ruby interpreter without modifying the path directly. Just run the following command

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways of handling this, particularly if you have to deal with rails 2 apps on the same system, is with [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) -- using it, you can can easily install multiple rubies (and sets of gems to go along with them), and switch between them with e.g. `rvm use 1.9.2`. You can even set it up to automatically switch to the right ruby when you cd into a project directory, described [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/).

Comment: His question says he uses RVM.